# VBA - How to combine the [For loop] and [If statement] within a [For each loop]?

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a problem with combining the [for loop] with the [if statement] inside the [for each loop]. I expected the [for loop] could help me to repeat the range of the cell, then I didn't need to make it long. However, the result is not something I want.

Here is the code I am working on. To simplify the question, I have rephrased the structure of it.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim SelectRange As Range
Dim test_counter As Long


Set SelectRange = Range("A1:G10")
SelectRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2


For Each eCell In SelectRange
    If eCell.Value <> "" Then
        test_counter = test_counter + 1
        Debug.Print test_counter
    
            For i = 1 To 5
                If Range("B" & i).Value = "test" Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"
                Else
                    Debug.Print "BYE"
                End If
            Next i
         
    End If
Next eCell

End Sub
```

The cell [B1] to [B5] is `test`, `test`, `test`, `test`, `NONONO` for testing.

The result:
`1`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`BYE`
`2`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`BYE`
`3`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`BYE`
`4`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`BYE`
`5`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`yes`
`BYE`

my expected result:

`1` `yes` `2` `yes` `3` `yes` `4` `yes` `5` `BYE`

It could be like this by not using [for loop]:

```
For Each eCell In SelectRange
    If eCell.Value <> "" Then
        test_counter = test_counter + 1
        Debug.Print test_counter
    
                If Range("B1").Value = "test" Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"
                ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "test" Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"
                ElseIf Range("B3").Value = "test" Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"
                ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "test" Then
                    Debug.Print "yes"
                ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "NONONO" Then
                    Debug.Print "BYE"
                End If

    End If
Next eCell
```

It is simple if it is only B1 to B5, but it could be painful if I have to do hurdred of it. Is it any method I could achieve the result by using [For loop]? Many thanks.

---

Update on 17/6/2023

I feel like my above expression is not clear enough, sorry for that. I'll update the example and trying to explain it step by step.

First, I like to introduce the new setting of the excel sheet:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1QxU.png)

Then I put this code to work:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim SelectRange As Range
Dim test_counter As Long


Set SelectRange = Range("A1:G10")
SelectRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2


For Each eCell In SelectRange
    If eCell.Value <> "" Then
    'if the eCell is not empty, change it to the blue colour
        If eCell.Address = "$C$2" Then
        'only if the C2 cell can jump out the loop
            Debug.Print "I'am free! YES! I'm not blue color!"
        Else
            eCell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    End If
Next eCell



End Sub
```

The result is work, the `C2` cell jump out the loop, it is not changed to blue colour. The other cells which not empty have changed to blue.

This time, I want the Cell `C2:C7` can escape the blue colour, so I use the for loop, I thought it could work again(but it didn't...).

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim SelectRange As Range
Dim test_counter As Long


Set SelectRange = Range("A1:G10")
SelectRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2


For Each eCell In SelectRange
    If eCell.Value <> "" Then
        For i = 2 To 7
            If eCell.Address = "$C$" & i Then
                Debug.Print "I'am free! YES! I'm not blue color!"
            Else
                eCell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next eCell



End Sub
```

I figure out why it is not work. Since when i = 2, the `C2` is not turning into blue, yes. However, all the `C3:C7` turning into blue at this moment. Next, when the i = 3, the `C3` is already turning into blue, and the `C2` will turn into blue in this moment. I just can't figure out how to escape the whole `C2:C7` for changing to blue by using for loop.

---

For more information, I am also like to put a piece of my exact project here to explain why I want to achieve this by using for loop. (Although it might make it more complicated.)

```
With Me
    For Each fC In .Controls
        If TypeOf fC Is MSForms.TextBox Then
'            For i = 34 To 43
                If fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 1).Name Then
                    'Nothing to do. Stay to normal textbox
                ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & i).Name Then
                    'Nothing to do. Just stay to normal textbox
                Else
                    tbCnt = tbCnt + 1
                    ReDim Preserve allTextbox(1 To tbCnt)
                    Set allTextbox(tbCnt) = New clsTextbox
                    Set allTextbox(tbCnt).tb = fC
                    'all the other textbox change to the new clsTextbox
                End If
            next i
        End If
    Next fC
End With
```

It is not work because of the reason I mention above. I can achieve it by typing all the exception like this:

```
With Me
    For Each fC In .Controls
        If TypeOf fC Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 1).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 34).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 35).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 36).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 37).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 38).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 39).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 40).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 41).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 42).Name Then
                'nothing
            ElseIf fC.Name = Controls("TextBox" & 43).Name Then
                'nothing
            Else
                tbCnt = tbCnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve allTextbox(1 To tbCnt)
                Set allTextbox(tbCnt) = New clsTextbox
                Set allTextbox(tbCnt).tb = fC
            End If
        End If
    Next fC
End With
```

I think it must have some ways be more effective. Please give me a help. Thanks.

Comment: Your question (and code) doesn't make sense. You seem to iterate over cells in a range (A1:G10). Once a non-empty cell is encountered you try to ... do.. what? Try to explain this "what" more clearly. Now it seems that you check all 5 cells in B1:B5 and depending on the values you output "yes" or "Bye"... Why? What are you really trying to do

Comment: @Gowire Hi, It seems like nonsense just because I had replace my code by using simple code, trying not to make it too complicated. Seems like I have failed to express my intention. The reason for me to use [for loop] in my code is, I am trying to figure out how to use [the loop] to repeat the number of times to make the `"B" & i` as the exception. In my original code, I made some textboxes and convert it all to something else by using "for each textbox in the userform", however, some of it I want to keep it as the normal textbox. That's why I want to make some `"B" & i` as the exception.

Comment: @Gowire ...Continue... For some textbox, let's say textbox1 to textbox39, I want to make it to the exception by using `for i = 1 to 39`, trying to make textbox 1 to 39 not convert into something else. Turn out the result is not something I want. Then I got the above question: How to make the `"B" & i` to be the exception, when it involve the if-statement. Let exaggerate my example. For each eCell the SelectRange, all of the SelectRange's background colour turn to black, only if some cells could be the exception. ie, `B7:B55`. Is it something I could achieve by the `for each`?

Comment: Could you please update the OP with these additional details? Perhaps add some in-code comments explaining what the goal of each section is? I'm still struggling to understand why this inner loop is necessary; it consists of static values that will be evaluated the same every step of the `FOR EACH` and doesn't contain any dependencies.

Comment: @Vince I just updated the detail and trying to explain the reason of using `for` loop. If it is not clear enough, please let me know and I will do my best to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Exit For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exit-statement) will stop iterating on the innermost `FOR` loop when the condition is met. It's better to use the innermost `IF` statement to store the result of the conditional, then apply the modification after the `FOR` loop. Using the the coloring example:

```
Sub test()
    Set SelectRange = Range("A1:G10")
    SelectRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    
    For Each eCell In SelectRange
        bIgnore = FALSE                               'will be TRUE to ignore cell
        If eCell.Value <> "" Then
            For i = 2 To 7
                If eCell.Address = "$C$" & i Then
                    bIgnore = TRUE                    'Mark the cell to ignore
                    Exit For                          'Escape inner FOR loop
                End If
            Next i

            'Modify unflagged cells 
            If bIgnore = FALSE then eCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    Next eCell
End Sub
```

In the case of your TextBoxes, if they're all named the same (`TextBoxN`) then you could make use of a [`SELECT CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) as an alternative to `IF/ELSEIF`. `SELECT CASE` has more flexibility when you have ranges of accepted inputs. Here's an application using your TextBox code

```
With Me
    For Each fC In .Controls
        If TypeOf fC Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            'Remove "TextBox" from the control name, leaving just the number
            Select Case INT(Replace(fC.Name,"TextBox",""))
                   Case 1, 34 To 43                 'Do nothing for all these
                   Case Else                        'Process everything else
                        tbCnt = tbCnt + 1
                        ReDim Preserve allTextbox(1 To tbCnt)
                        Set allTextbox(tbCnt) = New clsTextbox
                        Set allTextbox(tbCnt).tb = fC
            End Select
        End If
    Next fC
End With
```

Comment: Brilliant! The way you using flag to control the condition is so smart. Moreover, I just learnt that the SELECT CASE can use `34 to 43` directly. It is so silly I was trying to use `for loop` to achieve that. Many thanks for your kind help!